# Where to get the vertx dashboard monitor?

Tags: java, microservices, vert.x

I have seen a couple of times on vertx website a vertx dashboard monitor, that looks like:

[image]

How to setup the dashboard or how to get it?

Answer (score 1):

The dashboard was built by Eric Zhao one of the Google Summer of Code students in 2016. The dashboard is not part of any official component however the student did a great job modularizing the code and you can see it at the blueprints project:

https://github.com/sczyh30/vertx-blueprint-microservice/tree/master/monitor-dashboard